# Adjusting the size of \rightleftarrows in mathmode with mt2pro[lite]

Tags: characters, mtpro, times

I'm using `\mt2pro[lite]` version. The symbol `\rightleftarrows` near the system's characters is too large in width in my opinion. I would like that `\rightleftarrows` smaller and lower. I tried to insert `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`. The result is the symbol does not fit well to the nearby characters. Exist an character of `\mt2pro[lite]` that I can substitute it?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{book} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{times,mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{Lorentz2}
\left\{\begin{aligned} 
x&\,{\scriptscriptstyle \rightleftarrows}\, x'\\
y&\,{\scriptscriptstyle \rightleftarrows}\, y'\\
z& \,{\scriptscriptstyle \rightleftarrows}\, z'\\
t& \,{\scriptscriptstyle \rightleftarrows}\, t'\\
v&\,{\scriptscriptstyle \rightleftarrows}\! -v\\
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I apologize if I do not understand when to ask a question.

Comment: Your minimal example is not complete: the package `amsmath` is missing (it is needed for the `aligned` environment), and I don't know in which package the `\rightleftarrows` command is to be found. Maybe in these mtpro2 fonts… which are not installed in my distribution (TeX Live). Probably because they don't have a free license.

Comment: Sincerely I have not here my complete source .tex where there are many package. Can you adjust it?

Comment: @Sebastiano In what sense `\rightleftarrows` is “too big”? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @Sebastiano You are asking multiple questions about changing individual characters after selecting  mtpro. Really it is a strange approach, a font set is a coherent design work by an individual, as a general rule you should accept it or choose a different font, changing individual characters may sometimes be needed to overcome bugs or exceptional circumstances but it should be a rather rare thing to do.

Comment: If you don't need it to present it in different math styles, then you could always scale it, as in `\newcommand\myrightleftarrows{\mathrel{\scalebox{.9}[.8]{$\rightleftarrows$}}}`.  However, I would heed David's warning in this regard and not pursue this approach.  Note, technically, if you want it centered on the math axis, you would need  `\newcommand\myrightleftarrows{\mathrel{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{.9}[.8]{$\rightleftarrows$}}}}}`.

Comment: As usual I get only a lot of criticism just because with my heart in hand I do not have the time to adjust the source and are without internet at least to figure out what I can do by myself. For me the character `rightleftarrows` was too big and I did not know how to decrease the size with the characters in times. And as usual there are always those who vote negative my question.

Comment: @Sebastiano Can you please explain what the desired output should look like? Maybe produce a mock-up of what it should look like? You already managed to decrease the size of the arrows, the fact that the "symbol does not fit well to the nearby characters" is to be expected as you changed the size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really see how the arrows are “too big”.

Anyway, here's a simplistic definition:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{book} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{times,mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\newcommand{\srightleftarrows}{%
  \mathrel{\scriptstyle\rightleftarrows}%
}
\newcommand{\ssrightleftarrows}{%
  \mathrel{\scriptscriptstyle\rightleftarrows}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\left\{\begin{aligned} 
x& \rightleftarrows x'\\
y& \rightleftarrows y'\\
z& \rightleftarrows z'\\
t& \rightleftarrows t'\\
v& \rightleftarrows -v\\
\end{aligned}\right.
\qquad
\left\{\begin{aligned} 
x& \srightleftarrows x'\\
y& \srightleftarrows y'\\
z& \srightleftarrows z'\\
t& \srightleftarrows t'\\
v& \srightleftarrows -v\\
\end{aligned}\right.
\qquad
\left\{\begin{aligned} 
x& \ssrightleftarrows x'\\
y& \ssrightleftarrows y'\\
z& \ssrightleftarrows z'\\
t& \ssrightleftarrows t'\\
v& \ssrightleftarrows -v\\
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you go for the scriptscriptstyle, here's a better rendering:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{book} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{times,mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\newcommand{\srightleftarrows}{%
  \mathrel{\scriptstyle\rightleftarrows}%
}
\newcommand{\ssrightleftarrows}{%
  \mathrel{\vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\rightleftarrows$}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\left\{\begin{aligned} 
x& \ssrightleftarrows x'\\
y& \ssrightleftarrows y'\\
z& \ssrightleftarrows z'\\
t& \ssrightleftarrows t'\\
v& \ssrightleftarrows -v\\
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very compliment with all my heart +1. Why all users vote my questions with a downvote? My english is very bad. Probabily They not understand my question. I ask you to kindly help me to edit my questions to make me understand what I want. I'm making a book that I keep very much.

Answer (score 3):

Like David, I recommend against this.  But I will show one possibility.

I don't have `mtpro2`, so I perform this on the CM font. As in my comment I suggest scaling the glyph horizontally and/or vertically to suit.  In this implementation, I make sure the result is `\mathrel`,  centered on the math axis, and I code it to support all math styles.  For demonstration, I scale the original by 85% horizontally and 75% vertically.

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{book} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{times,mathtools,amssymb}
%\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\myrightleftarrows{\mathrel{\ThisStyle{\vcenter{\hbox{%
  \scalebox{.85}[.75]{$\SavedStyle\rightleftarrows$}}}}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\text{original}\left\{\begin{aligned} 
x&\rightleftarrows x'\\ 
y&\rightleftarrows y'\\ 
z&\rightleftarrows z'\\ 
t&\rightleftarrows t'\\ 
v&\rightleftarrows -v\\ 
\end{aligned}\right. 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\text{revised}\left\{\begin{aligned} 
x&\myrightleftarrows x'\\ 
y&\myrightleftarrows y'\\ 
z&\myrightleftarrows z'\\ 
t&\myrightleftarrows t'\\ 
v&\myrightleftarrows -v\\ 
\end{aligned}\right. 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
x\myrightleftarrows x'\quad
\scriptstyle x\myrightleftarrows x'\quad
\scriptscriptstyle x\myrightleftarrows x'
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

One of the many reasons why this is a bad approach, in general, is that it changes the stroke width of the glyph, which will tend to make it seem incompatible with other glyphs.